# Binary operator cannot be applied to NSpredicate and int

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have an `EventDec` entity, which has `eventStatus` attribute and I just want to display the result of that attribute. Here is my code

```
 let fetchRequestDec = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "EventDec")
    fetchRequestDec.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"eventStatus = %i")
    let result = fetchRequestDec.predicate
 if (result == 1)
    {
      print("Status = 1")
    }
    else 
    {
      print("Status = 2")
    }
```

So I am doing filtering wrong as I am getting this error. How do I resolve this?

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to NSpredicate and int

Comment: It's not the filtering, it's the result == 1 lines. result is an NSPredicate, 1 is an int, therefore the binary operator '==' cannot be used.

Comment: Ok, so how do you resolve that

Comment: Either assign an int value to result (let result = 4, or whatever), or compare it to another NSPredicate (if result == NSPredicate(format:"eventStatus = 6")). I can't tell you exactly what to do, without more information about what this snippet is supposed to do. What exactly are you checking?

Comment: eventStatus contains values of 1 and 2. So I like to display what is inside of eventStatus, so that I can display the message accordingly

Comment: Okay. Will the format of the NSPredicate, then ALWAYS be of the format: 'eventStatus = 1' or 'eventStatus = 2'? This is VERY important, because you'll have to parse the String, and some stray whitespace at the end could cause your app to crash.

Comment: yes, it will be always 1 and 2

Comment: You've broken line: NSPredicate(format:"eventStaus = %i"). It's must be as an " eventStatus = %i ". Right?

Comment: Okay. I'll have an answer for you in a minute. I want to confirm that my substring knowledge is up-to-date.

Comment: No, I don't  have a broken line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to use a predicate? Your question seems to want to return the EventDec object and print the eventStatus attribute. You need to perform a fetch. Get the results array. Extract what you want. No filtering required.

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<EventDec> = EventDec.fetchRequest()
if let results = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest) {
   for result in results {
     print("Status = \(result.eventStatus)")
   }
}
```

This assumes your managedObjectContext is called context.
Also you have a typo `eventStaus` a instead of `eventStatus`

Comment: Just realised I had <NoteLocation> from my own code still in the fetchRequest. If you change it to `let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<EventDec> = EventDec.fetchRequest()` does that help?

Comment: I tried that, it just print outs Status = /(result.eventStatus)

Comment: I'm sorry I've been trying to answer this on an iPad. On a laptop now so less typos, I hope. That line should be `print("Status = \(result.eventStatus)")`

Answer (score 1):

Alright, glad I checked this in a playground, because Apple made lots of substring changes with Swift 3.0. Try this, to print your predicate's Int value (you can also access the value, by changing the code a bit):

```
let index = fetchRequestDec.predicate.predicateFormat.index(fetchRequestDec.predicate.predicateFormat.endIndex, offsetBy: -1)
print("Status: \(Int(String(fetchRequestDec.predicate.predicateFormat[index]))!)")
```

Comment: Value of type'NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestresult>' has no member predicate format

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry, the property is an NSPredicate. I'll update my answer right now.

Comment: What should fetchRequestDec be? As I don't see you involved eventStatus attribute. So I am getting nil (fatal error)

Comment: I'm using your var names. fetchRequestDec has a property called, predicate, that is an NSPredicate, according to this line: fetchRequestDec.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"eventStaus = %i") An NSPredicate's format can be accessed as a String from its predicateFormat property. The rest of my snippet takes the last character of that string and converts it to an Int, then prints it. There is nothing in my snippet about an eventStatus. That is part of your format strings and I'm counting from the end. Where do you get a nil value?

Comment: Thanks for your help.